# How can I take information from a text box and move it into a paragraph element?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, submit

I am a total newbie when it comes to javascript. I have a text box and a button associated with it. When I run the onclick function I want to take the information from the text box and move it to:

"When the submit button is clicked using the onclick function the text would move from the text box to here.

.

I've tried a lot of different stuff but no luck so far. 
Thanks for the help.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include what you've tried so far.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online. I suggest you consult [one of them](http://www.w3schools.com/html/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to use jQuery, here's a simple solution.

```js
    /**
     * Using jQuery, grab the <pre> element on the page, and fill
     * them with the text within the textarea.
     */

    function moveText() {
      "use strict";
      $("pre").html($("textarea").val());
    }

    /**
     * Using pure javascript, do exactly the same thing as moveText();
     */

    function pure_js() {
      "use strict"
      document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHTML;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea>Default text.</textarea>
  <button type="button" onClick="pure_js()">Move the Text</button>
  <pre></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using jquery. As I am new, I haven't had the chance to take a look at jquery yet. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I edited my post above to include a pure JS version of doing the same thing. _Note the function name in your onClick call of your button element._